# Changing a defcustom value in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

I'm trying to augment the following `defcustom` block:

```
(defcustom latex-unicode-math-mode-rules-doublestruck
  '(("\\mathbb{F}" "")
    ("\\IF" ?)
    ("\\mathbb{N}" "ℕ")
    ("\\IN" ?ℕ)
    ("\\mathbb{Q}" "ℚ")
    ("\\IQ" ?ℚ)
    ("\\mathbb{R}" "ℝ")
    ("\\IR" ?ℝ)
    ("\\mathbb{Z}" "ℤ")
    ("\\IZ" ?ℤ))
  "Double struck letters for `latex-unicode-math-mode'."
  :type '(repeat (list :tag "Rule"
                       (string :tag "Input")
                       (choice :tag "Output" string character)))
  :group 'latex-unicode-math
  :set 'latex-unicode-math-mode-set-variable
  :initialize 'custom-initialize-default)
```

by adding the rules

```
("\\mathbb{P}" "ℙ")
("\\IP" ?ℙ)
```

Simply inserting the rules into the `defcustom` block and reloading my `.spacemacs` doesn't seem to work. Is there some special way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`C-M-x` on the defcustom.  `C-h k C-M-x` in an Emacs-Lisp buffer tells you:

> **`C-M-x`** runs the command `eval-defun`, which is an interactive compiled
>   Lisp function in `elisp-mode.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-M-x`.
>
> `(eval-defun EDEBUG-IT)`
>
> Evaluate the top-level form containing point, or after point.
>
> *If the current defun is actually a call to `defvar` or **`defcustom`**,
>   evaluating it this way **resets the variable** using its initial value
>   expression* (using the defcustom’s :set function if there is one), even
>   if the variable already has some other value.  (Normally `defvar` and
>   `defcustom` do not alter the value if there already is one.)  In an
>   analogous way, evaluating a ‘defface’ overrides any customizations of
>   the face, so that it becomes defined exactly as the ‘defface’ expression
>   says.
>
> If `eval-expression-debug-on-error` is non-`nil`, which is the default,
>   this command arranges for all errors to enter the debugger.
>
> With a prefix argument, instrument the code for Edebug.
>
> If acting on a `defun` for FUNCTION, and the function was
>   instrumented, `Edebug: FUNCTION` is printed in the echo area.  If not
>   instrumented, just FUNCTION is printed.
>
> If not acting on a `defun`, the result of evaluation is displayed in
>   the echo area.  This display is controlled by the variables
>   `eval-expression-print-length` and `eval-expression-print-level`,
>   which see.

Answer (score 0):

Drew's answer covers the question you have actually asked; however...

I can see that `latex-unicode-math-mode-rules-doublestruck` is a user option defined as part of the `latex-unicode-math-mode` package available on MELPA.  I presume you have installed this package.

Copying the entire definition of that option into your init file and then modifying it is not the correct way to customize an option.  You should never need to copy the *definition* of a variable/option into your init file (and doing so may well not have the desired effect, or could potentially cause you problems later on if the upstream definition changed).

Instead, simply type:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option` <kbd>RET</kbd> `latex-unicode-math-mode-rules-doublestruck` <kbd>RET</kbd>

(If Emacs tells you the option does not exist, you will need to `M-x load-library` the `latex-unicode-math-mode` library.)

You can then `INS`ert your additional rules via the UI, and use the "Apply and Save" button to permanently save your customized value in your config.